# Client-side JavaScript field validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, client-side-validation

I have a particular scenario that I need a bit of help with in terms of client-side validation.

I have some input fields that are required (not HTML required) but they are identified as required using a class called "requiredInput" and is evaluated on server-side when the user clicks on the submit button.

I, however, would like to validate the input fields client-side when the user moves away from that field and disable submit till all the required fields are filled in.

How do I go about this scenario in order to handle this client-side completely rather than waiting for the server-side submit to perform the validation?

```
<input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="requiredInput" tabindex="3">
```

**Note:** I don't want to perform the validation on submit, I would like to validate onblur and disable submit till all the required fields are filled in.

Comment: Hello @DurgpalSingh, I don't want to perform the validation on submit rather I'd like to do that onblur of an input field.

Comment: html5 has a 'required' attribute that works pretty well.  otherwise there is something like this: https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 1):

You have bunch of JS validation packages that you can find accros the internet.

For now I think one of the best is [ParsleyJS](http://parsleyjs.org/). You can use few build-in (and some extra) validators that work perfectly on client side. Ypou can design your own once. There is also possibility to validate field remotly which is also fine if you don't want to send whole the form to the server.

Comment: Another one is the jQuery Valitation Plugin, included with some Bootstrap templates. It is really easy to use. It validates based on the id of the input. It has a few builtin methods, has a tag here on StackOverflow and allows you to create custom methods too.

Comment: Hello @Filip: ParsleyJS looks very promising, however, it doesn't give me the option of validating the field onblur? I currently already have that functionality of validating on submit.

Comment: Well yes I gives you validation on blur

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't a pure js solution and want full control of what exactly is valid you might want to do something like this:

Create a `validateInput()` function that gets all the input fields, checks if they have content (and whatever other checks you might want to perform) and proceed with enabling the submit button if everything is as expected. Attach that function to the onblur event of each input field.

```
function validateInput(){
  let validInput = true;
  let field1Content = document.getElementById('field1').value;
  let field2Content = document.getElementById('field2').value;
  if(field1Content.length === 0 || field2Content === 0)
      validInput = false;

  if(validInput)
    //enable submit button
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Easly do this if you have Jquery, try below

```
<input type="text" name="lastName" id="txtbox1" class="requiredInput clsValidate" tabindex="3">
<input type="text" name="lastName" id="txtbox2" class="requiredInput clsValidate" tabindex="3">
<input type="text" name="lastName" id="txtbox3" class="requiredInput clsValidate" tabindex="3">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
    ValidateInput();
});

$(document).on('change', 'input.clsValidate[type=text]', function () {
    ValidateInput();
});

function ValidateInput() {
    var cnt = 0;
    $('input.clsValidate[type=text]').each(function (i, obj) {
        if ($(this).val().trim().length <= 0) {
            cnt++;
        }
        if (cnt > 0) {
            $('#btnsubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
        } else {
            $('#btnsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, this is fine but this is just enabling and disabling the submit button. Can I not just trigger the validation on the field because once it makes a server-side round trip, it does show the error based on that class.